# Error 403 when accessing JSP

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-403

Below is my index.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%!
static int counter=0;
%>
<%
session.setAttribute("counter","Counter-"+counter);
counter++;
for(int id=0;id<60;id++)
{
System.out.println(id+"\tRequest Is Being Processsed for :"+(String)session.getAttribute("counter"));
try{
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
out.println("<h2>Request Processing Completed");
%>
```

When i hit the application from browser I get the below exception.

Error 403--Forbidden
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.4 403 Forbidden

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If
>   the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public
>   why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason
>   for the refusal in the entity. This status code is commonly used when
>   the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been
>   refused, or when no other response is applicable.

Need help fix this and also need to know why is the error coming anyways ?

Comment: Can you provide your url like http://localhost:8080/yourapp/...jsp?

Comment: http://10.10.226.171:7555/workmanager/index.jsp                 This url is generated by the testing tab of the application server so i believe nothing wrong with that. The server logs does not show any information however, application monitoring reveals that the request is bieng processes by the Application server hosting my application.

Answer (score 0):

The deployed war file was not built properly causing this issue